# When passing containers by reference, is auto parameter or template deduction better?

Tags: templates, c++14, auto, ranged-loops

What are the differences, if any, between

```
template <typename T, int N>
void input (T (&Array) [N])
{
    for (T& val: Array) cin >> val;
}
```

and

```
template <typename T>
void input (T (&Array))
{
    for (auto& val: Array) cin >> val;
}
```

and

```
void input (auto& Array)
{
    for (auto& val: Array) cin >> val;
}
```

?

Which is better?

All of them work correctly with `double store[5]` but not with `vector <double> store`

Side note: The first version won't compile with `T (&Array) []` since that is a "reference to array of unknown bound". The second won't compile if we wrote `T& val: Array` instead.

Comment: The big difference, for better or worse, is that there are a LOT more types that can be passed to `input()` in the second version. i.e. it will work with `std::vector` or `std::list`

Comment: note to someone inquiring about the second case: there can be redundant parentheses around any declarator, e.g. `int((*(x)));` is the same as `int *x;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Frank pointed out, the first version takes in arrays only, while the second and third can also take in a `vector` or `list`

The second and third versions don't seem to work with `vector <double> store` because the `for` loop is not executed when the vector is empty.

Replace it with `vector <double> store (5, 0)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of an array argument, these all have the same behaviour. In the first one `T` is deduced to the element type; in the others, `T` or `auto` deduces to the array type.

Of course, the second and third forms (which are equivalent except that you can't write a specialization for the `auto` one) permit non-array arguments to be passed.